# iPhone - Set Button back to initial state

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I created a button using a play and stop image, what I want is when i press play and that the sound finishes, the stop image should go back to play, but it's not working, can anyone help here please. cheers.

```
- (IBAction)play {

    if(clicked == 0){
        clicked = 1;
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/TEST.wav", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

        NSError *error;
        audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
        audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;


        [audioPlayer play];
        [start setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"stop.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    } 
    else{
        [audioPlayer release];
        clicked = 0;
        [start setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pla.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } 

}

//If user does not do anything by the end of the sound set the button to start
- (void) audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying: (AVAudioPlayer *) player
                        successfully: (BOOL) flag {
    if (flag==YES) {
        [start setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pla.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

This is my .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

int clicked;

@interface _0_RabbanasViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroll;
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
    IBOutlet UIButton *start;

    IBOutlet UIImage *iPla;
    IBOutlet UIImage *iStop;
    BOOL successfully;

}

- (IBAction)play;
- (IBAction)next;

@end
```

Comment: does setting the image to "pla.png" manually work (when pressing stop)?

Comment: Yes, when I click on the play, the audio will play and the stop image will appear, and when I click on stop it will stop the audio and show the play. I just don't know what to add when it's playing and reaches the end, the stop should show.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set the delegate of the AVAudioPlayer instance to self:

```
[audioPlayer setDelegate:self];
```

and in the header file, subscribe to the AVAudioPlayerDelegate protocol:

```
<AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
```

Now it should work.

EDIT: Here's where to subscribe to the AVAudioPlayerDelegate protocol:

```
@interface _0_RabbanasViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate> {

IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroll;
AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
IBOutlet UIButton *start;
...
```

Hope it works now. :)

EDIT2: Set audioPlayer delegate to self here:

```
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;
[audioPlayer setDelegate:self];
[audioPlayer play];
```

EDIT3: Add this:

```
- (void) audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying: (AVAudioPlayer *) player
                        successfully: (BOOL) flag {
    if (flag==YES) {
        clicked = 0;
        [start setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pla.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, I dont understand where you want me to put the code, would you mind adding the code to the code I've posted please. Cheers.

Comment: add [audioPlayer setDelegate:self]; just before [audioPlayer play]; , can you post your corresponding .h file so I can show you where to put the other bit?

Comment: +1, idipro has to check if audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying is called at all

Comment: Comments can't be multi-line, edit your original post and put your .h file in there. :)

Comment: thats done now, sorry im new in here :) - #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

Comment: Where do I put this please [audioPlayer setDelegate:self];

Comment: it's working, but i have to click twice(probably in the state clicked=0), do i have to set a 3rd action?

Comment: Set clicked to 0 in the audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:successfully: method

Comment: Please click the check mark so this is marked as the answer to your question. You're welcome. :)